# How do I format labels for the tick marks in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm finding it very difficult to find what I want in the `pgfplots` manual.  In particular, I would like to personalize how the labels for the tick marks are typeset.  Finding the correct keywords is very aggravating.  For example, in the following code, I would like only the tick marks to be set in san serif; everything else should be in the normal font.  But, nothing I do seems to make a difference.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}%%
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    every x tick label/.append style={font=\itshape,yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
                    every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily,xshift=0.75ex},
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
                    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
                   },
            x=1.65pt,
            y=2.25pt,
            }

\begin{document}

\newcommand\aemass{(50 / 2 ^ ( x/28) )}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            %<only applies to titles but not tick labels>% font=\sffamily,
            title={Mass of Strontium-90 after $t$-days \textsf{1,2,3,4,5,}},
            xlabel={time (in days)},
            ylabel={mass (in milligrams)},
            xmin=0,xmax=170,
            ymin=0,ymax=64,
            grid=both,
            xtick={0,10,...,160},
            ytick={0,2,5,...,60},
            ]
            \addplot [domain=0:170,samples=64]({x},{\aemass});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `font` keyword respect changes in the size of the font, but not the face of the font (such as san serif, italic, or bold).

While it would be nice to be told what keyword I should be using here, it would be even better if someone could tell me about I could write a macro that will handle the formatting and to get `pgfplots` to know to use that macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because labels are in math mode so they don't apply right away. You can change this behavior by redefining the label printing command. I've done it here just for x to show the difference. Alternatively you can use a sanserif math font for the labels via Lua/XELaTeX

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}%%
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    every x tick label/.append style={font=\itshape,yshift=0.75ex,rotate=0},
                    every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily,xshift=0.75ex},
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
                    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel,rotate=90},
                   },
            x=1.65pt,
            y=2.25pt,
            }

\begin{document}

\newcommand\aemass{(50 / 2 ^ ( x/28) )}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
  font=\sffamily,
  xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
            title={Mass of Strontium-90 after $t$-days \textsf{1,2,3,4,5,}},
            xlabel={time (in days)},
            ylabel={mass (in milligrams)},
            xmin=0,xmax=170,
            ymin=0,ymax=64,
            grid=both,
            xtick={0,10,...,160},
            ytick={0,2,5,...,60},
            ]
            \addplot [domain=0:170,samples=64]({x},{\aemass});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that even though I added `0` t the `xtick` and `ytick`, neither got added to the axes.  While I don't need both, how would I get the `ytick` for `0` to appear?